# Block QA deploy if Alpha tests fails in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

The issue we've encountered is that sometimes, even when our tests fail, the QA pipeline can still be triggered manually. To address this, I'm working on implementing a mechanism to automatically block the QA deployment if our initial alpha tests have not passed successfully. We have release/other pipelines that are branched off from master that do not have the alpha stage but only have qa. Is there a way we can go back and check alpha stage tests whether they passed or failed before letting them run qa in the new branch?

Here's the technical breakdown:

Current Setup: We have a software development pipeline consisting of multiple stages. One of these stages is the alpha testing stage.

Objective: Our goal is to ensure that the QA deployment stage, which comes after the alpha testing stage, is blocked if the alpha tests fail.

Problem: Currently, there's no built-in mechanism to prevent the QA deployment from happening even when the alpha tests fail.

Solution Approach:

One approach we're considering is implementing a system that checks the status of the alpha tests and, if they haven't passed successfully, prevents the QA deployment from proceeding.
To achieve this, we're also exploring the idea of associating the status of alpha tests with the branch from which the release is cut.
If the alpha tests are successful for a branch, the release pipeline can proceed; otherwise, it should be blocked.

I am trying to figure out how to do this in gitlab but not sure if there is a native way or a simple method to get this done

We have tried using allow_failure: true and have also tried using  needs:project directive that allows us to fetch artifacts from other jobs in a different pipeline, and can be configured to fetch from the same project.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking the keyword `needs`. It will allow you to execute a job based on the execution of other job(s).

Here is an example:

```
stages:
    - alpha
    - QA_deployment

alpha:
    stage: alpha
    script: 
        - echo "The alpha stage must pass so that the QA_deployment stage would be triggered otherwise the QA_deployment won't be triggered"
        - echox
QA_deployment:
    stage: QA_deployment
    needs: ["alpha"]
    script:
        - echo "running QA_deployment"
```

[1) wrong command in script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBgqc.png)

[2) alpha stage fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hH9Gu.png)

[3) QA_deployment Skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kiIn.png)